# How to install applets on SSD?

Tags: javacard, globalplatform

I am trying to install a simple Javacard applet on a SSD in my card. But I receive `6985` (Condition of use not satisfied).

```
D:\CardTools> python install_on_ssd.py

Connected to Card. ATR: <Censored>

***** STEP 01: Mutual Auth with ISD
---> 00 A4 04 00 08 A0 00 00 01 51 00 00 00
<--- 90 00
---> 80 50 00 00 08 07 95 E3 6B 7C 2B 96 0B
<--- 00 00 12 81 18 38 33 20 19 73 01 02 00 37 59 40 AE F9 C1 36 A6 0D 5B 09 E0 8D 2E D1 90 00
---> 84 82 00 00 10 C2 BA 4C 00 80 78 96 5B 54 C1 2B A7 F4 C1 71 84
<--- 90 00

***** STEP 02 : Install SSD
---> 80 E6 0C 00 1E 07 A0 00 00 01 51 53 50 08 A0 00 00 01 51 53 50 41 06 11 22 33 44 55 66 01 84 02 C9 00 00
<--- 00 90 00

**** STEP 03 : Mutual Auth with SSD
---> 00 A4 04 00 06 11 22 33 44 55 66
<--- 90 00
---> 80 50 00 00 08 A3 AC D2 73 A3 98 1E A5
<--- 00 00 12 81 18 38 33 20 19 73 01 02 00 38 A1 10 A3 9D 71 D0 67 E2 0D 85 2F 7B 0B 5E 90 00
---> 84 82 03 00 10 96 F3 83 9A B6 E4 46 DA 5A 04 CA 54 CD EE 22 B2
<--- 90 00

**** STEP 04 : Update SSD GP Keys
---> 84 D8 00 81 50 D2 F8 63 2B CF 26 4C 32 65 B0 BD EF 67 B8 4B 5F 62 CA BD 63 8E 77 EE FB EB BC 88 54 15 4A 85 C8 9A CA CA C0 9F 9D 0C B8 77 41 0C A3 8A 00 41 5A CC E9 47 FA D8 46 9B EB FC C8 5A FE 4C 5A 78 C2 2D 97 CC B6 6A DC 18 04 BC DA 60 4C 94 23 9A 34
<--- 01 A4 B7 D6 A4 B7 D6 A4 B7 D6 90 00

***** STEP 05 : Mutual Auth with SSD
---> 00 A4 04 00 06 11 22 33 44 55 66
<--- 90 00
---> 80 50 00 00 08 AB ED 75 BE EE 42 24 DF
<--- 55 66 12 81 18 38 33 20 19 73 01 02 00 00 89 FF 49 11 CD A8 AA 11 09 4D 7D 1E 86 C1 90 00
---> 84 82 03 00 10 12 AA 56 F4 26 87 F6 43 A0 F1 9C A2 AD C4 CB AC
<--- 90 00

***** STEP 06 : Install Applet.
---> 84 E6 02 00 20 55 3D 9B F7 00 AC 2F 21 C7 0D 81 28 55 3D 83 F0 7C 1E CF 51 0F F0 78 57 BF 98 1C F5 9A 58 EF 0B
<--- **Fail** 69 85
Failed to install applet. INSTALL for LOAD returns 6985
```

Note that

1. I have tried different installation parameters and privileges in the *STEP 02* (SSD installation), but in all cases I received the same SW in the applet installation step.
2. The sample applet which I want to install, does not import any special package. It only returns 9000 to all APDUs.

Comment: Is your SSD in `PERSONALIZED` state after key load?

Comment: Yes, the SSD is PERSONALIZED. The ISD was in OP_READY state, but I tried the process with ISD in INITILIZED and SECURED too. but both have same result.

Comment: Has the SSD the Authorized Management Privilege? Does the ISD enforce Mandated DAP Verification privilege?

Comment: @k_o_ How can we check if the ISD enforce Mandated DAP Verification? I checked the ISD privileges and they are: `Privs:    SecurityDomain, CardLock, CardTerminate, CVMManagement, TrustedPath, AuthorizedManagement, TokenVerification, GlobalDelete, GlobalLock, GlobalRegistry, FinalApplication, ReceiptGeneration` .The SSD does not have Authorized Management Privilege. Is it mandatory for SSD? (OP is my colleague)

Comment: @EbrahimGhasemi: It is possible to have an SSD which is managed by the the ISD, hence the SSD cannot control its own contents. Giving the AuthorizedManagement is worth a try.

Comment: @k_o_ I'll give it a try. But in such a case (SSD cannot control its own contents), what is the usage of that SSD?

Comment: @EbrahimGhasemi: I'm referring to the GP specification v2.3.1, sect. 9.3.2:
"A Security Domain with Authorized Management or Delegated Management privilege may load an Executable Load File to any Security Domain. The Executable Load File is subject to acceptance by the receiving Security Domain where applicable." Authorized Management can manage the whole card, Delegated Management needs a signed token. This token permits the installation of a single application. This signed token could be provided by the card issuer giving away part of the control to a different SSD to install an applet.

Comment: @EbrahimGhasemi: See my more complete answer below. The SSD is still useful without this feature, e.g. to be able to isolate data so that the SSD cannot access shared data from the ISD or vice versa. Or to fulfill other GlobalPlatform tasks like DAP verification, Token Verification, ..

Answer (score 1):

Please check if your SSD is able to manage its own contents. The privilege Authorized Management should be set for this. Also Delegated Management can be used for this. GP specification v2.3.1, sect. 9.3.2 defines these requirements.

Authorized Management can manage the whole card, Delegated Management needs a signed token. This token permits the installation of a single application. This signed token could be provided by the card issuer giving away part of the control to a different SSD to install an applet.

If none of these permissions is given, the SSD is a security container isolating the data from other SDs, but the SSD is not able to manage the contents. The SSD is still useful without this feature, e.g. to be able to isolate data so that the SSD cannot access shared data from the ISD or vice versa. Or to fulfill other GlobalPlatform tasks like DAP verification, Token Verification, ...